# Trying to compile libpng VS2019 options.awk: bad line (10): com CMake Error at scripts/gensrc.cmake:68 (message): Failed to generate pnglibconf.tf5

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, libpng

i try to compile libpng version 1.6.38  using Visual Studio 2019 C++
and im getting this error :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: genfiles, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Generating pnglibconf.c
1>options.awk: bad line (10): com
1>CMake Error at scripts/gensrc.cmake:68 (message):
1>  Failed to generate pnglibconf.tf5
1>
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(231,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

this is my pre processor defines :

```
WIN32
_WINDOWS
NDEBUG
PNG_NO_MMX_CODE
CMARK_STATIC_DEFINE
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
CMAKE_INTDIR="Release"
```

what is the sulotion for this error ?

Comment: This seems to be a line ending issue. It's already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547342/libpng-building-issue-on-windows-10).

Answer (score 3):

This happens, because according to your PATH CMake uses Cygwin version of awk(gawk) which cannot process files with CRLF endings.
Open the generated file libpng/bin/scripts/gensrc.cmake and find there the line which looks as "set(AWK "<path_to_awk>")" and you will see, which awk CMake uses in your case.

I had the same problem recently. In order to find the cause I added "set(CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO STDOUT)" into scripts/gensrc.cmake.in to see exact awk commands and modified options.awk as follows:

```
# com <comment>
#   The whole line is placed in the output file as a comment with
#   the preceding 'com' removed
{ print "Line: '"$0"'" } #
$1 == "com"{
   if (NF > 1) {
      # sub(/^[     ]*com[  ]*/, "")
      $1 = ""
      print comment $0, cend >out
   } else
      print start end >out
      print "$1='"$1"'" #
      print "NEXT"      #
      next
}
$1 != "com"{
      print "$1='"$1"'" #
      print "CONTINUE"  #
}
```

When I compared the output of C:/Cygwin64/bin/gawk.exe and a Windows-compatible C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gawk.exe I saw that Cygwin gawk has CR character inside $1 (see the screenshot).

[image: diff]

So the solution is either to use Windows-compatible awk tool or to correct line endings.